# PHP Validation and Site Redirection

Tags: php, html

I have looked around for "PHP validation and redirection" but so far they don't work me because I cannot execute PHP scripts inside a HTML page because my website hosting does not give me access to the apache config httpd file. I can add handlers but I don't think that helps me. Here's what I'm trying to do:

1. User inputs some stuff including a valid email address
2. PHP creates a json string and save it on the server (works)
3. Write an email to the user confirming what they've entered (works)
4. Re-direct after the submit which is from the following code:

   ```
   <form method=POST action="go.php">
          <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
   </form>
   ```
5. If the user has entered anything invalid (email, name...) the PHP script should return the user to the previous page with a red * beside the field that's invalid.

My question is, how can I do that without putting PHP inside the html?

Comment: I would like to help you. but some time it is a good idea to change host provider and do thing in php. alternative html5 with javascript might do some of the job in your case.

Comment: "I cannot execute PHP scripts inside a HTML page" So save the .html file as a .php file and have the php script output the html as required